# object not found error when uploading app to shinyapps.io that works in Rstudio

Tags: r, deployment, shiny, rstudio

Anyone know how to approach troubleshooting this error?:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : object 'BPT' not found
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue with this object was that as I was generating the app the object was stored locally, and not generated by the up to date version.  I added a seed object that could then be modified by the selectInput values in the app.